# How can I use CONCAT_WS on grouped queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use `CONCAT_WS` on grouped queries?

Here is my database table:

### items

```
id(PK)  itemcode    req_id(FK)  qualifications  duties
```

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT *,CONCAT_WS(' ',itemcode) itemcodes,COUNT(*) counter FROM items
    WHERE req_id=1 GROUP BY qualifications,duties
```

I'm hoping that the output would be the row plus the `itemcode` separated by spaces. Say, if there are four rows, I would get: `code1 code2 code3 code4` in the `itemcodes` field. However, it only returns ONE of the item codes.

Sample database entries:

```
id  code    req_id  qualifications  duties
------------------------------------------------------
1   code12  1       can read        do the laundry
2   code24  1       can read        do the laundry
3   code35  1       can read        do the laundry
4   code47  1       can read        do the laundry
5   code98  1       can write       draw animals
6   code02  1       can write       draw animals
7   code53  2       can sing        sing all the time
```

Desired output:

for `req_id=1`

```
(*) itemcodes                       counter
-------------------------------------------
    code12 code24 code35 code47     4
    code98 code02                   2
```

Comment: Any fiddle you can provide ?

Comment: [Here you go!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91d7de/4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT qualifications, duties, GROUP_CONCAT(itemcode SEPARATOR ' ') AS itemcodes, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM items
WHERE req_id = 1
GROUP BY qualifications, duties
```

**`GROUP_CONCAT`** is used to group multiple rows. It is an aggregation function.

**`CONCAT_WS`** is used to concatenate multiple strings, using a separator. All strings must be passed as argument, it is *not* an aggregate function.

Comment: question is **How can I use CONCAT_WS on grouped queries?**

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT. :) Thank you!